# assistance needed With ArrayList Synchronizing

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety

I'm trying to make a tile based game. I made a `Tile` class and gave each one it's own `Rectangle` for collision. Once I render and update them, I store all of them into an `ArrayList`. That part works fine, but when I try to access that same `ArrayList` from another class through a getter, I get none of the elements. I check the size with my console, and it gives me the right number, but when I try to actually get an element 
i.e. `rect.get(0)`, I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

I think it's a thread safety issue, but I've tried everything I could think of from using the `synchronize` keyword to `Collections`, but no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Edited With Code. Sorry about not posting it earlier

```
public class Launcher extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 1500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 900;

    private static final String title = ("Game Alpha");

    volatile boolean running;

    Thread CT;

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    Camera camera;

    Controls controls;

    PlayerTest pt;

    BufferStrategy BS;

    Graphics graphics;

    //I'm declaring the arrayList here
    public  ArrayList<Rectangle> bounded = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    public Launcher() {

        Sprites.resources();
        controls = new Controls();
        GUI();
        //The camera class is the one in which I'm trying to access the list
        //It's there right now just to test, I plan on changing it later
        camera = new Camera(this, controls, 0, 0);

        pt = new PlayerTest(this, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);

        Tiles.tileSets();

        CT = new Thread(this);
        START();

    }

    public void GUI() {
        setTitle(title);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addKeyListener(controls);

        canvas.setPreferredSize(size);
        canvas.setMaximumSize(size);
        canvas.setMinimumSize(size);
        canvas.setFocusable(false);
        add(canvas);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void render() {
        BS = canvas.getBufferStrategy();

        if(BS == null) {
            canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }


        graphics = BS.getDrawGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        Rectangle cam = new Rectangle((int)camera.getX(), 
                (int)camera.getY(), 
                camera.getWidth(), 
                camera.getHeight());

        //Here I'm looping to get my tiles
        for(int x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 64; y++) {
                Tiles.getTile(LevelCode.code[y][x]).setBounds( x * 50 - (int)camera.getXof(),  y * 50 - (int)camera.getYof());

                //Here I'm adding the rectangles from each tile into the array
                bounded.add(new Rectangle(Tiles.getTile(code[y][x]).getBounds()));

            }   
        }

        pt.render(graphics);

        BS.show();
        graphics.dispose();
//Here after I render the tiles I clear the list, for my updates, then //repopulate
        bounded.clear();

    }

    public ArrayList<Rectangle> getList() {
        return bounded;
    }

}
```

Comment: We can't debug code that we don't see. Please build a testable minimal example. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think this is more a design problem than a multi-threading problem. You can make methods thread-save by using the keyword "synchronised". So please insert some code example.

Comment: I bet 100 SO points that he's got 2 lists, and the one he tries to read is empty.

Comment: Try formatting your question. The whole thing probably shouldn't be a single paragraph. Also use code blocks on your function calls and error messages.

Answer (score -1):

Synchronize (if done properly) means this is not a thread safety issue, although you haven't posted the actual code so it's possible you are doing it wrong.

The most likely case here is that there are actually multiple `ArrayList`s and you accessing the wrong ones. Try checking the id (the number after the # when you `toString`) it and make sure it is the same for both places.